Getting child’s app list without FamilyActivityPicker
I implemented parents to manage their children's apps with FamilyActivityPicker.
Then, is there way to get child’s(or my) app list without FamilyActivityPicker?
Because for parents using android, i might need to send tokens of app list to server.

No.  There is not.  The tokens are opaque values that can only be passed to iOS SDKs.  There is no point in holding them on your server or in an Android device.

@Paulw11 ok thanx for your comment

@FurangMoon No, you can not do that. Recently i have work with same kind of app where we try to apply multiple solutions but did not work for us. Without FamilyActivityPicker it's not possible!!
